# single quote in e-mail addresses + echoing it in a $_SESSION + SQL select

Tags: php, email, quote

I'm writing a mail form in order to allow users to send e-mail from a contact PHP page.

I make use of a REGEX to validate the e-mail address and perform lots of checks on the different fields.

If the user makes a *'mistake'*, the form gets deflected to a second page, echoing all the fields (those which are ok and the one not) and showing in red where the problem is ( "You forgot to fill in the Captcha", " you forgot to fill in your name", ect ....). The echoing of the fields is done thanks to $_SESSION in the `<input type='text'>`'s value

Everything worked brillantly until I had the idea of typing an e-mail address containing a single quote ( As it's valid )

**Problem 1:**
Our old friend **jim_o'brien** becomes **jim_o**   when it's echoed.

**Problem 2:**
As I want to limit the sending of e-mail to 1 every 24h, I check in the DB if the Ip address or ... the e-mail address has already been recorded less than 24 hours ago and here => **the SQL SELECT fails**

**Questions** :

- What are the reasons of these 2 phenomenons ?
- Is it impossible to accept single quote in e-mail and to do, at the same time, the checks I want?
- Side question : what are the characters, usefull in an XSS or SQL injection, that are *at the same time* forbidden in an e-mail address?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1. I presume you're inserting the address into the `value` tag of the `<input/>` element. So it becomes `<input type='text' value='jim_o'brien'/>`. Do you see the problem with the quote there? It's terminating the value. The solution is to use the `htmlentities()` function:

```
echo "<input type='text' value='".htmlentities($_SESSION['email'], ENT_QUOTES)."'/>";
```

This should also protect you from XSS injection.

Problem 2. You don't show your code that queries the DB, but it sounds like you may not be dealing with quotes properly there, either.  If you use prepared statements, this shouldn't be a problem, and it will protect you from SQL injection. If you're still using the mysql_XXX functions, so you can't use prepared statements, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on all user inputs being inserted into SQL.

You can get the full syntax of email addresses from [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5322).

Comment: GREAT ! I've just made a few tests, it aparently solves problem 1 **and** problem 2. It's seems the single quote was terminating the query too. I do not use prepared statements , that's why I'm trying to devise own filters to protect. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi again, just to be sure ... I did the following : `$query_write   =" INSERT INTO ipmail VALUES ( '".$ip."',0,'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sender_email'])."','".$now."','".$datetime_sto_dom."','".$_POST['sender_name']."')";`. **jim_o'brien@thing.com** appears unprotected in the DB , but I assume the escape is invisible, am I right ?  On the other hand is it necessary to use htmlentities on update queries : `$query_upda   =" UPDATE ipmail SET date_long='".$now."', date_time='".$datetime_sto_dom."' WHERE mail='".htmlentities($_POST['sender_email'], ENT_QUOTES)."' ";`THANKS

Comment: The escape is just part of the syntax of the `INSERT` statement, to keep the quote from being treated as the end of the string; it's not actually put in the DB. `htmlentities` should be used when substituting into a web page, `mysql_real_escape_string` when substituting into an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
You should convert the single quote to an html entity. Replace the single quote with `&lsquo ;`. But without the space between the last character and the semicolon.